# Make and Visualise table in R

Tags: r, visualization

First I have an input and I want to get an output like this
(I want to group the occurrences in the dataset between columns):

[image]

Second: 
Display this table in a good looking way (something that looks like Word or Excel) 
I can't use Word or Excel as I'm making some calculations in R with this dataset (it contains columns with numbers which aren't displayed here)

Answer (score 1):

## calculating the output table

I don't really see how the output table is calculated. Shouldn't it be `output_table["A", "C"] = "e"`?

## Displaying your data

There are a lot of ways to do that. You might consider using [`RMarkdown`](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) to create a report-style output.

The [`DT`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) library is also a very handy tool to display tables. It works well with `RMarkdown` and can be embedded in HTML documents. If you are using [`RStudio`](https://www.rstudio.com/), you can use the following code to display your data

```
library(DT)
DT::datatable(iris)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, seems like it was easy I just have to make cell by cell in the dataframe (it's long but it does the trick)

Comment: But I'm trying to integrate the R code in Power Bi and I don't really know if the result will be displayed ( for instance Plotly doesn't work but ggplot does )

Comment: Since embedding html in Power Bi is possible, both plotly and DT should be usable.

Comment: It doesn't execute though in the R script :/